# iPad apps. Exit(0) stay on 'taskbar'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios

(ios 4.2)
When I force quit the application (exit(0);), the application quit, but the iPad "taskbar" doesn't seems to be refresh(app stay on it)

Do you have this behaviour?  If no, how did you completely close?

(i know force quit are not "Apple friendly", but it's for a custom app)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you fully read the iOS Human Interface Guidelines? If not, **do it now** before continuing! The HIG also mention about the app switcher.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the fate of your app's process is, its icon will always remain on the app switcher, as a "recently-used" app, until the user taps and holds, and removes it using the minus icon. I don't believe there's anything you can do to make iOS not display it there.

The process will already have quit, though, since you told it to `exit(0)`.

Comment: To expand on this, what you're calling a "taskbar" is just a list of recently launched applications, designed to help you get to programs you've been using recently more quickly. It communicates nothing about what's currently loaded and what isn't. If you remove something that is currently running from the list then it is also terminated in current iOS, but that's a transient implementation detail rather than the point of the interface.

Comment: True. Apple cares about user experience. Many users even don't know what multitasking means, but use it anyway. If something suddenly disappears some users may get scared. Then, if it also disappears from the App Switcher they get a heart attack.

Comment: @Radek S: What happens if it disappears from the device altogether?